# Toggling comment on entire Python function/method in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The shortcut for toggling comment on entire function that works for Javascript does not work in Python.

Is there some way to achieve equivalent functionality for Python?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

[image]

1. Fold (<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067767/how-do-i-collapse-sections-of-code-in-visual-studio-code-for-windows)

[image]

2. Select line down (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>)

[image]

3. Toggle Line Comment (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>).

[image]

and then you're done. (The function is even unfolded automatically because it is commented out.)